# React Native - Targeting S+(version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent

Tags: android, react-native, android-pendingintent, react-native-share

I'm using the react-native-share package to share a component as an image. It works fine on Android versions below 33, but on Android 33, it throws an error: 'Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a Pending Intent.' How can I fix this issue?

After updating react-native-share package its says,

react-native-share compile SDK Version is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-share'.

> Could not set unknown property 'namespace' for extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.

```
buildToolsVersion = "33.0.2"
minSdkVersion = 21
compileSdkVersion = 33
targetSdkVersion = 33
```

On my app/build.gradle file inside dependencies

implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1'